# Calculate difference between between two consequent Redux states

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The case is following - there is a map with the markers which are added and removed according to the selected filters.

Right now we have an old-skool JS app where we calculate delta between updated and previous datasets and instead of completely redrawing all the markers on the map we are removing obsolete and adding new markers.

This gives us a smoother UX. How to do that with Redux?

Comment: You need to provide some kind of context, what does your current data structure for storing the markers look like, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "automatic" way to do it - it requires an actual comparison operation between the old and new state values.  Generally speaking, you'd either do that in a middleware after the action has been reduced, or in a store subscriber.

Fortunately, it turns out that there's a number of addon packages that do this already.  My [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) has links to a number of libraries that do this sort of thing, particularly in the [DevTools](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md) and [Store](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md) categories.

Comment: this is what I mean - isn't there is an only one copy of state exists in the given time.
I mean of course, I can store the previous state in the window object, but isn't there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: Nope.  One way or another, you have to have a reference to the old state and a reference to the new state to compare them.  Redux deliberately does not provide anything fancy - it's up to a user to decide what they want to do on top of that.